# How to get memory offset?

Tags: memory, offset

I need to get memory offset from struct, the file is: https://github.com/BlastHackNet/mod_s0beit_sa/blob/master/src/samp.h I need to get

```
    struct stObject : public stSAMPEntity < object_info >
{
    uint8_t             byteUnk0[2];
    uint32_t            ulUnk1;
    int                 iModel;
    uint8_t             byteUnk2;
    float               fDrawDistance;
    float               fUnk;
    float               fPos[3];
    // ...
};
```

fPos memory offset( as 0x1111 ). I don't know how to do it. Please help me.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at the `offsetof` operator: http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstddef/offsetof/

Comment: so actually i have to run that code right? cause it's .dll file and it's hard to make it to show offsetoff, run that code.

Comment: If you have the headers, you could just write a little test program to output what the offset is..